# Create a sentence with Buttons and TextViews together

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I've been looking for an answer for this issue for over a week with no luck, so I'm creating the question here :)

I'm creating a sentence where the user needs to select some options to complete it.
The sentence needs to look natural and not to be broken by line jumps.

The components used are:

`TextView` - `Button` - `TextView` - `Button` - `TextView` - `Button`

The desired result is:

```
“How far can I go with” 
'20 liters' "if I filled 
in" 'diesel fuel' "if 
the economy is" '10 ltr/100 km'
```

but once all the options are chosen, the screen becomes:

```
“How far can I go with”
'20 liters' "if I filled in"
'diesel fuel'
"if the economy is"
'10 ltr/100 km'
```

I need this to look natural and try to put the Buttons inside the TextViews.

I know in iOS there's a component called "UI Collection View" to accomplish this behavior, but I can't find the similar in Android.

Thank you!

Added a couple of pics to clarify.

[empty values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyXwu.png)

[with values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSbZD.png)

EDIT:

The idea is to get...

```
 xxxxxxxxxxx
 Button xxxx
 xxxx Button
 xxxxxxxxxx
 Button
```

where `X` is the Text

Comment: Use [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear) with `android:orientation="horizontal"`.

Comment: @Dumbo Is like this at the moment, but the textViews are going under the button if the text is too large.

Comment: If it is too long to display it on the screen, it moves `TextView` below. But how do you think it should look like if it is too long? I guess then you can try to make smaller text font

Comment: @Dumbo I'm working with different languages strings, in English can be fine but in other languages like Spanish or Italian is taking much more. Reduce the text size is not an option :(

Comment: Then you can use scroll-able (horizontally) TextView or Activity Layout

Comment: Thanks @Dumbo , but I think we are talking about different things here :) 
Please check my latest edit to the main question to see the expected result, no scroll in any direction, just fill the entire screen with button and texts together

Comment: So use `GridView`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using recyclerview with FlexBoxLayoutManager and two itemView types.(one of them should be textview and one of them will be button).

please check this url [Google FlexBox](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

Comment: The same result, the textViews are not splitting to fill the entire width.
If the text is too long, is going under leaving an empty space after the button.

Comment: flexbox is implemented for these situations. please read the flexbox documents and use the flexWrap option in a right way to fill entire width. you can see examples in mentioned link that filled entire row width

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/UiM4UQD . please check the result :) . (I'm hiding the real text values due a company privacy, sorry)

Comment: ok i understand what you mean now.it's not possible to fill width for widgets that are larger than blank spaces.

Comment: Thank you Reza. Is a shame that Android is not allowing that in the same way as iOS. Have a good one.